# Use Value of ASP.NET TextBox in SQL SELECT Query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Im looking at ASP.NET and I want to be able to use a value that a user types in a TextBox in a `SELECT` query to get that record.

For example, user types "1234" in the TextBox, and the SQL `SELECT` query gets the record with primary key value "1234" from the database and displays it on the page. Is this possible (programmatically or not)? Im using C# for my ASP.NET site as well. If you could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed possible to query a database in C# using dynamic values.  What you're looking for at this time is basically any tutorial to use your database (SQL Server?  something else?) in C#.  There are a variety of data access technologies you can choose from, but either way your next step is to find some tutorials on using a database in C#.

Comment: Make a search for "autocomplete textbox with ajax"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code snippet to get you started. Basically, you establish the connection and supply the textbox.Text value into the command's **Parameters** collection.

```
            using (SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand queryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();

                try
                {
                    // Open Connection             
                    thisConnection.Open();
                    
                    queryCommand.CommandText = @"select * from [YourTable] where id = @id";

                    queryCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", this.ID.Text);

                    SqlDataReader dr = queryCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    if (dr.Read())                                                    
                        this.message.Text = dr["id"].ToString();                        
                    else                                                   
                      this.message.Text = "ID not found";  
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                                                
                    this.message.Text = ex.Message;
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, would this code be placed within the TextChanged method of the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You need an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) like Entity Framework, Dapper ..etc. To map your objects (in your application) with the database objects (tables, views, sp ..etc.). Then, you can (from your application) query your database, update, delete, insert operation.

Then, from your code behind, you can get the selected value, and use ORM to process that value on the database.

This is basically what you need. The rest is a learning curve !